# How to gradually reflect the texture and leave the material?

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I created a printer and covers, and with the help of animation I need to show how gradually the textures are superimposed on the covers (as in printing). I do not know how to do this.

How can you make the cases run into the printer blank and then the textures appear as you print?
File blender - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NA3jwEbCeywVtkg5HVg6ovmJ-JcnWqMV/view?usp=sharing

[image: upd img nodes]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WGz6tHB.png

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sc5ewQh.png

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Instead of adding comments, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and nd **use the tools from this site to upload images** so that they are displayed as part of your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a mask with black and white (image or a gradient texture) and then use [Object] texture coordinate with an Empty selected to determine the physical location of that texture. You can then animate the location of that mask by either animating the mapping node location, or by animating the location of the empty itself. This also works for scale and rotation.

Use this mask then on a mix shader between two shaders, one with blank and one with the materials for the covers.

[image: Example of using texture coordinates based on an empty]

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot. But I still do not know how to proceed now. I have two materials on the model covers one transparent and one with texture. All the manipulations I did with the one with the texture. I dump the screen as you said. Did I miss something? How can I now make the white part transparent and the transition is more sharp between the picture and the transparent part? And how to make it not white and transparent? How is this second material? I do not know how to thank you for your reply!

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Npd4MEE.png

Answer (score 0):

[image: I finally figured it out]
I finally figured it out... All the nodes are shown on the screen below